# Laravel 4: Why is my partial mock of Auth failing?

Tags: laravel-4, mocking, partial

I'm doing some unit tests in a controller that handles some authentication stuff in my web app. I am testing that a redirect happens on a valid login. The relevant controller code is:

```
if ( Auth::attempt(Input::only(array('username', 'password')), 
Input::has('remember_me')) ) 
{
    Session::put('client.id', Auth::user()->client->id);
    Session::put('client.name', Auth::user()->client->name);
    return Redirect::intended('admin/listings');
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
public function testValidCredentialsRedirectToDashboard() {
    Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')->once()->andReturn(true);
    // Auth::makePartial();

    $this->call('POST', 'login',
        ['username'=>'foo', 'password'=>'bar']);

    $this->assertRedirectedTo('admin/dashboard');
}
```

When I leave the `makePartial` call commented, phpunit complains that

```
Method Mockery_1_Illuminate_Auth_AuthManager::user() does not exist on this mock object
```

But if I uncomment it xdebug complains about too much recursion:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! 
in /.../vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(16) : 
eval()'d code on line 307
```

(Turning xdebug off just yields a segmentation fault instead.)

I could just mock the user method, but I feel like that ties the test too close to the implementation. I don't want to test the Session stuff going on there, just that a login attempt is made and a redirect results.

Any ideas why `makePartial` is failing so miserably here?